# How to calculate ACF for multiple series and plot them all at once?

Tags: r, plot, time-series, advanced-custom-fields

I need to do an AR test and plot acf for many series. I can do it one by one like,

```
library(dplyr)
library(feasts)
library(tsibble)
data1 <- rnorm(70, 5, 2)
data2 <- rnorm(70, 3, 1)
data3 <- rnorm(70, 8, 3)
MONTH <- seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), by = "day", length.out = 70)
tstable <- data.frame(MONTH, data1,data2,data3)
tstable%>%as_tsibble(index = MONTH)%>%ACF(data1,lag_max = 7)%>%autoplot()
tstable%>%as_tsibble(index = MONTH)%>%ACF(data2,lag_max = 7)%>%autoplot()
tstable%>%as_tsibble(index = MONTH)%>%ACF(data3,lag_max = 7)%>%autoplot()
```

This is too much repetitive work. Is there a way to do the acf test and plot the series all at once? It doesn't matter if they are on the same graph or not. But it would be nice if different series can be labeled.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
plotACF <- function(data, vars, time_index, lag_max=7, rows=NULL){
  if(is.null(rows))rows <- ceiling(sqrt(length(vars)))
  glist <- list()
  for(i in 1:length(vars)){
    glist[[i]] <- data%>%
      as_tsibble(index = .data[[time_index]])%>%
      ACF(.data[[vars[i]]],lag_max = lag_max)%>%
      autoplot() + ggtitle(vars[i])
  }
  glist[["nrow"]] = rows
  do.call(cowplot::plot_grid, glist)
}

plotACF(tstable, c("data1", "data2", "data3"), "MONTH")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The following uses only base R:

**1)** `acf` can handle multiple series:

```
d <- data.frame(data1, data2, data3)
acf(d, lag.max = 7)
```

(continued after image)
[image: screenshot]

**2)** Using `d` from (1), if we don't want the ccf's we could generate just the diagonal of (1) like this:

```
opar <- par(mfrow = c(ncol(d), 1))
for(nm in names(d)) acf(d[[nm]], lag.max = 7, main = nm)
par(opar)
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

The {feasts} package which you are using to compute and plot the ACF works with multiple time series. In the {tsibble} package, multiple time series should be stored in a long format, and identified using a key variable. You can correctly format your data by pivotting longer here:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(feasts)
library(tsibble)
data1 <- rnorm(70, 5, 2)
data2 <- rnorm(70, 3, 1)
data3 <- rnorm(70, 8, 3)
MONTH <- seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), by = "day", length.out = 70)
tstable <- data.frame(MONTH, data1,data2,data3)
tstable <- tstable %>%
  as_tsibble(index = MONTH) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(starts_with("data")) 
tstable
#> # A tsibble: 210 x 3 [1D]
#> # Key:       name [3]
#>    MONTH      name  value
#>    <date>     <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 2010-01-01 data1  5.15
#>  2 2010-01-01 data2  1.89
#>  3 2010-01-01 data3 10.9 
#>  4 2010-01-02 data1  3.31
#>  5 2010-01-02 data2  5.90
#>  6 2010-01-02 data3  3.21
#>  7 2010-01-03 data1  4.58
#>  8 2010-01-03 data2  2.49
#>  9 2010-01-03 data3  1.58
#> 10 2010-01-04 data1  4.47
#> # … with 200 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Note how the "Key:" row now mentions that there are [3] series in the dataset.

---

Once your tsibble is correctly structured, you can estimate and plot the ACF:

```r
tstable %>% 
  ACF(lag_max = 7)
#> Response variable not specified, automatically selected `var = value`
#> # A tsibble: 21 x 3 [1D]
#> # Key:       name [3]
#>    name    lag     acf
#>    <chr> <lag>   <dbl>
#>  1 data1    1D -0.192 
#>  2 data1    2D -0.330 
#>  3 data1    3D  0.0213
#>  4 data1    4D  0.0786
#>  5 data1    5D  0.253 
#>  6 data1    6D -0.253 
#>  7 data1    7D  0.0152
#>  8 data2    1D -0.0116
#>  9 data2    2D  0.0959
#> 10 data2    3D -0.145 
#> # … with 11 more rows

tstable %>% 
  ACF(lag_max = 7) %>% 
  autoplot()
#> Response variable not specified, automatically selected `var = value`
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>